# wrapping a text url with <a> tags via jquery find and replace

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

I am pulling in tweets through a getJSON and writing them to a Google map infowindow with javascript. The problem is, these tweets come with text links but no formatting (and no ids/classes/anything for which to narrow a find and replace). This is the mash of code I'm using right now to find the text, but I can't get it to wrap whatever it finds in `<a>` tags to properly display the links:

```
function wrap( str ) {
    return '<a href="' + str + '">' + str + '<\/a>';
};

function replaceText() {
    var jthis = $(this);
    $("*").each(function () {
        if (jthis.children().length == 0) {
            jthis.text(jthis.text().replace(/\bhttp[^ ]+/i, wrap));
        }
    });
}
$(document).ready(replaceText);
$("html").ajaxStop(replaceText);
```

Did I overlook something or does anyone know a better way to do this?

Comment: if you don't want to use jQuery this works well: https://gist.github.com/ryansmith94/0fb9f6042c1e0af0d74f

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If i understand your problem right, this should work.
not sure why you are iterating through elements as regexp will scan all the text anyway.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
        function wrap( str ) {
            return '<a href="' + str + '">' + str + '<\/a>';
        };
        function replaceText() {
            $(".tweet").each( function(){
              $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/\bhttp[^ ]+/ig, wrap));
            })

        }
        $(document).ready(replaceText);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="tweet"> test 1 http://example.com/path </div>
        <div class="tweet"> test 2 http://example.com/path </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is definitely what I was looking for, but the issue is it being global. I can take that out, but it still tries to wrap urls in the header (like those referencing the gMaps API). Is there a reason for that, even though it's supposed to only be looking in "body"? (Changing that to document doesn't help, either).

Comment: i updated the example, this works fine without messing up urls in head

Comment: Just as a follow up, here's what I ended up using with success:

`function urlwrap( str ) { return '<a href="' + str + '" target="_blank">' + str + '</a>'; };
var text= 'data[i].text.replace(/\bhttp[^ ]+/ig, urlwrap)'`

and the text var was written to the page with information -- [i] -- parsed from the JSON response.